# Blur image in specific area of UIImageView where touch moved

Tags: objective-c, uiblureffect

I want to blur the part of image where I move the finger on image view similar to "Touch Blur" application. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library [ios-realtimeblur](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-realtimeblur) by passing the touch location along with the height and width you want for the same; also add that `view` as a `subview` of `UIImageView`. Make sure every time touch changes remove your previous blur view or change the frame of it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its adding blur to particular frame but what I want is add blur effect to all parts of image where I touched the image or the part where touch changes.